# Redirect MVC6 application on startup

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm interested to know if it is at all possible to redirect a user if a a web application hasn't been configured.

Initially I thought this could be done in the Configure method in the start.cs file, but something tells me this may not be possible.

Currently I'm checking for a configured state in my login controller, but to me this seems sloppy and as such I'm looking for a better solution, but I keep drawing a blank. That said what IS the best approach for this?

Comment: How do you determine whether the application has been configured or not?

Comment: I have a couple of different checks against the database to determine if the application is setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding some middleware at the beginning of the pipeline. (You can check [the middleware section](http://aspnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) of the asp docs for an overview. [This post](http://dzimchuk.net/post/understanding-aspnet-5-middleware) also has a very nice overview of the new middleware features in ASP 5).

A simple approach could be adding it as an inline middleware, before registering the MVC pipeline. Update the `Configure` method of **Startup.cs** as:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!YourWayOfCheckingIfAppIsConfigured())
        {
            //redirect to another location if not ready
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/NotReady");
            return;
        }

        //app is ready, invoke next component in the pipeline (MVC)
        await next.Invoke(context);
    });

    ... configure MVC
```

If you need a more complex piece of logic, you could encapsulate it in your own middleware class (See [Writing middleware](http://aspnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#writing-middleware) in the asp docs or [Middleware as a standalone class](http://dzimchuk.net/post/understanding-aspnet-5-middleware) section) and register it at the beginning of the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyWaitForAppStartupMiddleware>();
```